# Show div only on home page using code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to show a banner only on the homepage of my Codeigniter site but not sure how to do this. Here is my code.

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="susy__container bannercontainer" style="position: relative;">
      <h1 class="special">
       <span class="sp1">Affordable</span> 
       <span class="sp2">Business Websites</span> <span class="sp3">Done Fast…</span>
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle special">"Just find a website you like and we will customize it to your business needs, easy as 123!"</h2>
     <a href="../start" class="postbtn btn btn-orange">Start Search <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

I already tried this but shows blank page

```
<?php if( $this->uri->segment(1) == 'home' || $this->uri->segment(1) = '' ): ?>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="susy__container bannercontainer" style="position: relative;">
        <h1 class="special"><span class="sp1">Affordable</span> <span class="sp2">Business Websites</span> <span class="sp3">Done Fast…</span></h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle special">"Just find a website you like and we will customize it to your business needs, easy as 123!"</h2>
        <a href="../start" class="postbtn btn btn-orange">Start Search <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endIf; ?>
```

Comment: did u load url helper?

Comment: First, you will find routes.php in  application/config. And open the routes.php to notepad,or textedit.

Comment: Here have  your all url.

Comment: You will show homepage url. example: $route['default_controller'] = "home"; or $route['home'] = "home";

Comment: Next, You must open home control php file.

Comment: In application/controllers directory,for example if $route['default_controller'] = "welcome";, it is welcome.php.

Comment: And $route['*****'] = "home/homeview", controller code is homeview function in home.php of controller directory.

Comment: Next, You are following another helper.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter have mvc construct. Your code is view part.
So, You will insert php file of home page view  in application/views.

Comment: sorry I am new to codeignitor and not sure how to do this. I am looking for maybe a custom if statement

Comment: Do you not find view php file in home page?

Answer (score 0):

create a view file like banner and put your html code on it and load it on controller for eg like this .

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
     function Inventory()
     {
        parent::__construct();
     }

    function index()
    {   
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('home/banner');
        $this->load->view('home/home_view');
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }   
}
```

put your code in banner.php file and put it on view folder

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="susy__container bannercontainer" style="position: relative;">
        <h1 class="special"><span class="sp1">Affordable</span> <span class="sp2">Business Websites</span> <span class="sp3">Done Fast…</span></h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle special">"Just find a website you like and we will customize it to your business needs, easy as 123!"</h2>
        <a href="../start" class="postbtn btn btn-orange">Start Search <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by mistake i did not change function name as controller name note that please .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create three files `(header,homepage,footer)` in your VIEW:

Basic Example:

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('homepage');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}
```

In `homepage.php` add banner in this file along with home page HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="susy__container bannercontainer" style="position: relative;">
        <h1 class="special"><span class="sp1">Affordable</span> <span class="sp2">Business Websites</span> <span class="sp3">Done Fast…</span></h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle special">"Just find a website you like and we will customize it to your business needs, easy as 123!"</h2>
        <a href="../start" class="postbtn btn btn-orange">Start Search <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `header.php` file consist on your navigation, logo, css etc.

Your `footer.php` file consist on footer links, js, script,etc.